VLC segmentation fault when trying to play video RPi 3b
I see it complains about not finding a proper vout display in stack trace, but! It works fine on another RPi somehow. Please help. I had to chop off some lua and alsa debug info in the middle because of Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 37217
ST:
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126b)
[020244e0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01f85b58] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[020244e0] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[020023f0] gl vout display error: parent window not available
[020023f0] gles2 vout display error: parent window not available
[020023f0] xcb vout display error: window not available
[020023f0] fb vout display error: cannot get terminal mode (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
Segmentation fault
uid0001@rmpi:~$ cvlc -vvv -f -A alsa --alsa-audio-device hw:0 --play-and-exit upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126b)
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: VLC media player - 3.0.20 Vetinari
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: Copyright © 1996-2023 the VideoLAN team
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126b
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: configured with ./configure  '--build=arm-linux-gnueabihf' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf' '--runstatedir=/run' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-debug' '--config-cache' '--disable-update-check' '--enable-fast-install' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/vlc' '--with-binary-version=3.0.20-0+deb10u1' '--enable-a52' '--enable-aa' '--enable-aom' '--enable-aribsub' '--enable-avahi' '--enable-bluray' '--enable-caca' '--enable-chromaprint' '--enable-chromecast' '--enable-dbus' '--enable-dca' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--enable-dvdnav' '--enable-faad' '--enable-flac' '--enable-fluidsynth' '--enable-freetype' '--enable-fribidi' '--enable-gles2' '--enable-gnutls' '--enable-harfbuzz' '--enable-jack' '--enable-kate' '--enable-libass' '--enable-libmpeg2' '--enable-libxml2' '--enable-lirc' '--enable-live555' '--enable-mad' '--enable-matroska' '--enable-mod' '--enable-mpc' '--enable-mpg123' '--enable-mtp' '--enable-ncurses' '--enable-notify' '--enable-ogg' '--enable-opus' '--enable-pulse' '--enable-qt' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-samplerate' '--enable-sdl-image' '--enable-sftp' '--enable-shine' '--enable-shout' '--enable-skins2' '--enable-soxr' '--enable-spatialaudio' '--enable-speex' '--enable-svg' '--enable-svgdec' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-theora' '--enable-twolame' '--enable-upnp' '--enable-vdpau' '--enable-vnc' '--enable-vorbis' '--enable-x264' '--enable-x265' '--enable-zvbi' '--with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/' '--disable-d3d11va' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-directx' '--disable-dsm' '--disable-dxva2' '--disable-fdkaac' '--disable-fluidlite' '--disable-freerdp' '--disable-goom' '--disable-gst-decode' '--disable-libtar' '--disable-macosx' '--disable-macosx-avfoundation' '--disable-macosx-qtkit' '--disable-microdns' '--disable-mfx' '--disable-opencv' '--disable-projectm' '--disable-schroedinger' '--disable-sparkle' '--disable-srt' '--disable-telx' '--disable-vpx' '--disable-vsxu' '--disable-wasapi' '--enable-alsa' '--enable-dc1394' '--enable-dv1394' '--enable-libplacebo' '--enable-linsys' '--enable-nfs' '--enable-omxil' '--enable-udev' '--enable-v4l2' '--enable-wayland' '--enable-libva' '--enable-vcd' '--enable-smbclient' '--disable-oss' '--disable-crystalhd' '--disable-mmx' '--disable-sse' '--disable-neon' '--disable-altivec' 'build_alias=arm-linux-gnueabihf' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-OmfjZZ/vlc-3.0.20=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-OmfjZZ/vlc-3.0.20=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security ' 'OBJCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vlc-OmfjZZ/vlc-3.0.20=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: searching plug-in modules
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: loading plugins cache file /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/plugins/plugins.dat
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: recursively browsing `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/plugins'
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: plug-ins loaded: 516 modules
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: opening config file (/RMC//.config/vlc/vlcrc)
[01b53d78] main logger debug: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
[01b53d78] main logger debug: using logger module "console"
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: translation test: code is "en_GB"
[01bbb238] main keystore debug: looking for keystore module matching "memory": 4 candidates
[01bbb238] main keystore debug: using keystore module "memory"
[01b53b58] main libvlc debug: CPU has capabilities ARM_NEON FPU
[01bb2498] main input debug: Creating an input for 'Media Library'
[01bb2498] main input debug: Input is a meta file: disabling unneeded options
[01bb2498] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[01bb2498] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[01bb2498] main input debug: `file/directory:///RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' gives access `file' demux `directory' path `/RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[01bbb500] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[01bb6098] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 17 candidates
[01bb6098] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[01bc1fc0] main stream debug: creating access: file:///RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[01bc1fc0] main stream debug:  (path: /RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf)
[01bc1fc0] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 29 candidates
[01bc1fc0] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[01bc8490] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[01bc8490] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[01bc8490] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[01bc8490] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[01bc8490] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 296 bytes in 0s - 421 KiB/s
[01bc8490] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[01bc8d00] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[01bc8d00] playlist stream debug: using XSPF playlist reader
[01bc8d00] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "playlist"
[01bc8d00] main stream debug: stream filter added to 0x1bc8490
[01bcaeb0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[01bcaeb0] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[01bc96e8] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[01bc96e8] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[01bbb500] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf
[01bcaeb0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[01bcaeb0] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[01bbb500] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='directory' location='/RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' file='/RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf'
[01bb6098] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "directory": 55 candidates
[01bb6098] main demux debug: using demux module "directory"
[01bba440] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[01bba440] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /RMC//.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[01bba440] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[01bba440] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/meta/reader/filename.luac
[01bba440] lua demux meta debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/reader
[01bba440] main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
[01bb2498] main input debug: `file/directory:///RMC//.local/share/vlc/ml.xspf' successfully opened
[01bbac90] main xml reader debug: looking for xml reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
[01bbac90] main xml reader debug: using xml reader module "xml"
[01bb2498] main input debug: EOF reached
[01bb6098] main demux debug: removing module "directory"
[01bcaeb0] main stream debug: removing module "record"
[01bc8d00] main stream debug: removing module "playlist"
[01bc8490] main stream debug: removing module "cache_read"
[01bc1fc0] main stream debug: removing module "filesystem"
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: creating audio output
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: looking for audio output module matching "alsa": 5 candidates
...
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: USB PnP Sound Device USB Stream Output (usbstream:CARD=Device)
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: using audio output module "alsa"
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: keeping audio output
[01bf9418] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 19 candidates
[01bf9418] dbus interface debug: listening on dbus as: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
[01bf9418] main interface debug: using interface module "dbus"
[01bf25a0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[73500638] main input debug: Creating an input for preparsing 'serega_pirat_baik.mp4'
[01bf25a0] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[01bba440] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[01bba440] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[01bba440] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[01b53b58] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[01bba440] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dummy": 19 candidates
[01bba440] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[01bba440] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: starting playback of new item
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: resyncing on serega_pirat_baik.mp4
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: serega_pirat_baik.mp4 is at 0
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[72100668] main input debug: Creating an input for 'serega_pirat_baik.mp4'
[72f0b008] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: requesting art for new input thread
[72f0b008] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /RMC//.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[72f0b008] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[72f0b008] lua meta fetcher debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/meta/fetcher
[72f0b008] main meta fetcher debug: no meta fetcher modules matched
[72f0b008] main art finder debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
[72100668] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[72100668] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[72100668] main input debug: `file:///RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4' gives access `file' demux `any' path `/RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4'
[72d00938] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4' file='/RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4'
[72d00a60] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "file": 17 candidates
[72d00a60] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[72d00da8] main stream debug: creating access: file:///RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4
[72d00da8] main stream debug:  (path: /RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4)
[72d00da8] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "file": 29 candidates
[72d00da8] main stream debug: using access module "filesystem"
[72d00fb0] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "prefetch,cache_read": 26 candidates
[72d00fb0] cache_read stream debug: Using stream method for AStream*
[72d00fb0] cache_read stream debug: starting pre-buffering
[72d00fb0] cache_read stream debug: received first data after 0 ms
[72d00fb0] cache_read stream debug: pre-buffering done 1024 bytes in 0s - 3076 KiB/s
[72d00fb0] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "cache_read"
[72d01278] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "any": 26 candidates
[72f0b008] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /RMC//.local/share/vlc/lua/meta/art
[72f0b008] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/meta/art
[72f0b008] lua art finder debug: Trying Lua playlist script /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/vlc/lua/meta/art/00_musicbrainz.luac
...
[72d01278] lua stream debug: Trying Lua scripts in /usr/share/vlc/lua/playlist
[72d01278] main stream debug: no stream_filter modules matched
[72d07858] main stream_directory debug: looking for stream_directory module matching "any": 1 candidates
[72d07858] main stream_directory debug: no stream_directory modules matched
[72d00938] main input source debug: attachment of directory-extractor failed for file:///RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4
[72d01278] main stream debug: looking for stream_filter module matching "record": 26 candidates
[72d01278] main stream debug: using stream_filter module "record"
[72d00938] main input source debug: creating demux: access='file' demux='any' location='/RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4' file='/RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4'
[72d0b858] main demux debug: looking for demux module matching "mp4": 55 candidates
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: dumping root Box "root"
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   + ftyp size 24 offset 0
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   + moov size 91425 offset 24
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + mvhd size 108 offset 32
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + trak size 58253 offset 140
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 148
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + edts size 36 offset 240
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + elst size 28 offset 248
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + mdia size 58117 offset 276
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 284
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 95 offset 316
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + minf size 57982 offset 411
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 419
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 427
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 443
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 57918 offset 455
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 154 offset 463
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avc1 size 138 offset 479
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + avcC size 52 offset 565
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 24 offset 617
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 220 offset 641
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 1560 offset 861
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 21528 offset 2421
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stss size 152 offset 23949
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + ctts size 34272 offset 24101
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + vmhd size 20 offset 58373
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + trak size 32940 offset 58393
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + tkhd size 92 offset 58401
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + mdia size 32840 offset 58493
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + mdhd size 32 offset 58501
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 95 offset 58533
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + minf size 32705 offset 58628
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + dinf size 36 offset 58636
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + dref size 28 offset 58644
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + url  size 12 offset 58660
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + stbl size 32645 offset 58672
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsd size 105 offset 58680
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + mp4a size 89 offset 58696
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   + esds size 53 offset 58732
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stts size 24 offset 58785
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsc size 52 offset 58809
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stco size 1560 offset 58861
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + stsz size 30896 offset 60421
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + smhd size 16 offset 91317
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   + udta size 116 offset 91333
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   + meta size 108 offset 91341
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + hdlr size 33 offset 91353
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   + ilst size 63 offset 91386
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + gsst size 25 offset 91394
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + data size 17 offset 91402
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   + gstd size 30 offset 91419
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   |   |   |   |   |   + data size 22 offset 91427
[72d01278] mp4 stream debug: |   + mdat size 11254465 offset 91449
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: unrecognized major media specification (mp42).
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: found 2 tracks
[72d0b858] mp4 demux warning: elst box found
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug:    - [0] duration=179233ms media time=33ms) rate=1.0
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] read 386 chunk
[72d0b858] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[72d0b858] mp4 demux warning: CTTS table of 4282 entries
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] read 5377 samples length:179s
[72100668] main input debug: selecting program id=0
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: adding track[Id 0x1] video (enable) language undef
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x2] read 386 chunk
[72d0b858] mp4 demux warning: STTS table of 1 entries
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x2] read 7719 samples length:179s
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: adding track[Id 0x2] audio (enable) language eng
[72d0b858] main demux debug: using demux module "mp4"
[72100668] main input debug: looking for a subtitle file in /RMC/upload/
[72d0d7e0] main decoder debug: looking for video decoder module matching "any": 17 candidates
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: using ffmpeg Lavc58.35.100
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: CPU flags: 0x0000003f
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: allowing 5 thread(s) for decoding
[h264 @ 0x72d5c680] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x72d5c680] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: codec (h264) started
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: using frame thread mode with 5 threads
[72d0d7e0] main decoder debug: using video decoder module "avcodec"
[72dccda8] main decoder debug: looking for audio decoder module matching "any": 21 candidates
[72dccda8] main decoder debug: using audio decoder module "faad"
[72d013a8] main demux meta debug: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 2 candidates
[72d013a8] main demux meta debug: using meta reader module "taglib"
[72d0b858] main demux debug: removing module "taglib"
[72100668] main input debug: `file:///RMC/upload/serega_pirat_baik.mp4' successfully opened
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: elst (0) gives 0ms (movie)-> 33ms (track)
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: track[Id 0x1] using Sync Sample Box (stss)
[72d0b858] mp4 demux debug: stss gives 1 --> 0 (sample number)
[72100668] main input debug: Buffering 0%
[72100668] main input debug: Buffering 25%
[h264 @ 0x72d5c680] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x72d5c680] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: available hardware decoder output format 100 (vdpau)
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: available hardware decoder output format 46 (vaapi_vld)
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: available software decoder output format 0 (yuv420p)
[72100668] main input debug: Buffering 50%
[72dccda8] faad decoder warning: decoded zero sample
[72d0d7e0] avcodec decoder debug: trying format vaapi_vld
[72100668] main input debug: Buffering 75%
[6b04c038] main spu text debug: looking for text renderer module matching "any": 2 candidates
[01bb0b10] main playlist debug: reusing audio output
[72100668] main input debug: Buffering 100%
[72100668] main input debug: Stream buffering done (1250 ms in 8 ms)
[6b04c038] freetype spu text debug: Building font databases.
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: using ALSA device: hw:0
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug:  Hardware PCM card 0 'bcm2835 HDMI 1' device 0 subdevice 0
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug:  device name   : bcm2835 HDMI 1
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug:  device ID     : bcm2835 HDMI 1
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug:  subdevice name: subdevice #0
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: initial hardware setup:
ACCESS:  MMAP_INTERLEAVED RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  U8 S16_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: [8 16]
FRAME_BITS: [8 128]
CHANNELS: [1 8]
RATE: [8000 192000]
PERIOD_TIME: [10000 16384000]
PERIOD_SIZE: [80 131072]
PERIOD_BYTES: [1024 524288]
PERIODS: [1 128]
BUFFER_TIME: (416 16384000]
BUFFER_SIZE: [80 131072]
BUFFER_BYTES: [1024 131072]
TICK_TIME: ALL
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: channels map not provided
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: final HW setup:
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  S16_LE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: 16
FRAME_BITS: 32
CHANNELS: 2
RATE: 44100
PERIOD_TIME: 40000
PERIOD_SIZE: 1764
PERIOD_BYTES: 7056
PERIODS: (18 19)
BUFFER_TIME: (743038 743039)
BUFFER_SIZE: 32768
BUFFER_BYTES: 131072
TICK_TIME: 0
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: initial software parameters:
tstamp_mode: NONE
tstamp_type: MONOTONIC
period_step: 1
avail_min: 1764
start_threshold: 1
stop_threshold: 32768
silence_threshold: 0
silence_size: 0
boundary: 1073741824
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output debug: final software parameters:
tstamp_mode: NONE
tstamp_type: MONOTONIC
period_step: 1
avail_min: 1764
start_threshold: 1
stop_threshold: 32768
silence_threshold: 0
silence_size: 0
boundary: 1073741824
[01bcf8f0] alsa audio output warning: device cannot be paused
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: output 's16l' 44100 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/4 bytes
[6ae066d8] main volume debug: looking for audio volume module matching "any": 2 candidates
[6ae066d8] main volume debug: using audio volume module "integer_mixer"
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: input 'f32l' 44100 Hz Stereo frame=1 samples/8 bytes
[6ae07d50] main audio filter debug: looking for audio filter module matching "scaletempo": 16 candidates
[6ae07d50] scaletempo audio filter debug: format: 44100 rate, 2 nch, 4 bps, fl32
[6ae07d50] scaletempo audio filter debug: params: 30 stride, 0.200 overlap, 14 search
[6ae07d50] scaletempo audio filter debug: 1.000 scale, 1323.000 stride_in, 1323 stride_out, 1059 standing, 264 overlap, 617 search, 2204 queue, fl32 mode
[6ae07d50] main audio filter debug: using audio filter module "scaletempo"
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'f32l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Stereo->Stereo
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: conversion pipeline complete

[01bb5e10] main vout display debug: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 720x300
                                                                     [01bb5e10] main vout display debug: using vout display module "caca"
                 [01bb5e10] main vout display debug: A filter to adapt decoder VAOP to display RV32 is needed
                                                                                                             [01c183f8] main filter debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
                                                                                   [01c183f8] chain filter debug: Trying to use chroma I420 as middle man
                                 [01c0b2a0] main filter debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
       [01c0b2a0] vaapi_filters filter warning: Using SW chroma filter for 640x368 VAOP -> I420
                                                                                               [01c0b2a0] main filter debug: using video converter module "vaapi_filters"
                                                 [01c183f8] main filter debug: Filter 'VAAPI filters' (0x1c0b2a0) appended to chain
           [01c0b550] main filter debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
                                                                                                         [swscaler @ 0x1c598d0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
                                                                        [01c0b550] swscale filter debug: 640x360 (640x368) chroma: I420 -> 640x360 (640x368) chroma: RV32 with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
                                                                                           [01c0b550] main filter debug: using video converter module "swscale"
                                       [01c183f8] main filter debug: Filter 'Swscale' (0x1c0b550) appended to chain
                                                                                                                   [01c1[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: conversion: 'f32l'->'s16l' 44100 Hz->44100 Hz Stereo->Stereo
[6ae0eac8] main audio converter debug: looking for audio converter module matching "any": 9 candidates
[6ae0eac8] audio_format audio converter debug: f32l->s16l, bits per sample: 32->16
[6ae0eac8] main audio converter debug: using audio converter module "audio_format"
[01bcf8f0] main audio output debug: conversion pipeline complete
[6ae10ab0] main audio resampler debug: looking for audio resampler module matching "any": 4 candidates
[6ae10ab0] main audio resampler debug: using audio resampler module "ugly"
[6b04c038] freetype spu text debug: Took -59054 microseconds
[6b04c038] main spu text debug: using text renderer module "freetype"
[6b04fbf8] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
[swscaler @ 0x6b078060] Forcing full internal H chroma due to input having non subsampled chroma
[6b04fbf8] swscale scale debug: 32x32 (32x32) chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 (16x16) chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
[6b04fbf8] main scale debug: using video converter module "swscale"
[6b092c18] main scale debug: looking for video converter module matching "any": 17 candidates
[6b092c18] yuvp scale debug: YUVP to YUVA converter
[6b092c18] main scale debug: using video converter module "yuvp"
[6b049200] main video output debug: Deinterlacing available
[6b049200] main video output debug: deinterlace -1, mode auto, is_needed 0
[6b06fff0] main window debug: looking for vout window module matching "any": 6 candidates
[6b06fff0] main window debug: no vout window modules matched
[6b049200] main video output debug: Opening vout display wrapper
[01bb5e10] main vout display debug: looking for vout display module matching "any": 14 candidates
[01bb5e10] gl vout display error: parent window not available
[01bb5e10] gles2 vout display error: parent window not available
[01bb5e10] xcb vout display error: window not available
[01bb5e10] fb vout display warning: disabling TTY handling, use with caution because there is no way to return to the TTY
[01bb5e10] fb vout display error: cannot get terminal mode (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
[6b049200] main video output debug: deinterlace -1, mode auto, is_needed 0
[6b049200] main video output debug: Opening vout display wrapper
[01bb5e10] main vout display debug: looking for vout display module matching "any": 14 candidates
Segmentation fault


Seg faults should not happen even if there is some application failure (as you may already  know) and are usually indicative of an actual coding bug.

@goldilocks so what am i supposed to do? Should i bugreport this with ST to vlc devs?

As of now several people including me couldn't log in into VLC GitLab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/415478
this is getting ridiculous

Plz check if any libraries or depedencies are missing.

@liaifat85 i prayed for it to be this easy but no, all necessary libraries are present
